# qsub array job - get number of tasks

Tags: cluster-computing, sungridengine, qsub

Is it possible to get the number of tasks for a submitted array job? Like `$SGE_TASK_ID` for the task number.

For example if I submit the job

```
qsub -t 1-4 my_script.sh
```

I'd like to get `4`.

Comment: Are you wanting the total number or the id for the running job?

Comment: The total number of tasks. E.g. `4` if I call `-t 1-4`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any automatic variable to do that, but I can think of a way to do this via TORQUE (I'm betting that the same arguments work for SGE or have corresponding arguments). Unfortunately, you'd have to do it manually:

```
qsub -t 1-4 my_script.sh -v TOTAL_TASKS=4
```

Then, within the job script you'll have the environment variable $TOTAL_TASKS set as desired. This doesn't give it to you automatically but it will give you the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

I can obtain this information from `qstat -j <job_id>`.

For example, submit some array jobs:

```
echo "sleep 60" | qsub -t 1-200
```

Use qstat to extract total tasks:

```
qstat -j <job_id> | grep tasks
```

`grep` returns the following:

```
job-array tasks:            1-200:1
```